# Why the inconsistent responses from swipl?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'd like to understand why the interaction with `swipl` appears to be inconsistent.

Here's a typical example.  Suppose I have consulted a knowledgebase that includes the following definitions:

```
acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :- H  > A, acc_max(T, H, Max).
acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :- H =< A, acc_max(T, A, Max).
acc_max([], A, A).

max([H|T], Max) :- acc_max(T, H, Max).
```

Below I show what my screen looks like after I type `max([0, 1, 2], X).` at the prompt, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
?- max([0, 1, 2], X).
X = 2 ▮
```

(The `▮` indicates the position of the cursor.)

Note, in particular, that the interpreter's next prompt has not yet appeared.

Here's what the screen looks like after I type <kbd>;</kbd>:

```
?- max([0, 1, 2], X).
X = 2 ;
false.

?- ▮
```

Now I finally get the interpreter's prompt.

In contrast, below I show what my screen looks like after I type `max([2, 0, 1], X).` at the prompt, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
?- max([2, 0, 1], X).
X = 2.

?- ▮
```

Notice that this time I got the interpreter's prompt right away - I did not need to type <kbd>;</kbd>.  Also, there's no `false`.

I've found many other similar inconsistencies (e.g. sometimes the output `true.` shows up on the screen, but in other similar situations it doesn't).

As a newcomer to Prolog, I find such inconsistencies disconcerting (not to mention discouraging, since they are a constant reminder that I really have ***no clue*** of what's going on).

Is there a simple way to rationalize these inconsistencies?

Alternatively, is there some implementation of Prolog that provides a more consistent and predictable interaction than does SWI-Prolog?

Comment: This has to do with "choice points" in Prolog. In your first example, because of the order in which it found solutions relative to your input, Prolog had a choice point to explore after presenting the solution `X = 2`, so it searched for more but found no more solutions to the query. In your second case, the `X = 2` was determined and there were no choice points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as @lurker said, this is the result of choice points - cases where there is a rule that has not been evaluated, which may yield more solutions.

Let's go through an even simpler version of your example, `max([0,1],X).` vs `max([1,0],X).`.

`max([0,1],X).`:

This goes to `acc_max([1],0,X).`, which matches both `acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :-` rules. We evaluate them in the order that they appear:

First we see that `1 > 0` is true, and call `acc_max([],1,X)`. This matches only `acc_max([], A, A).`, and we therefore unify X with 1. We have a solution! But we also have a rule that has not been evaluated yet. This is where you see:

```
X = 1 ▮
```

So now we type <kbd>;</kbd>, and evaluate the second `acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :-` rule. We see that `1 =< 0` is not true, so this rule fails. We are now out of rules to try, so it turns out there are no more solutions. Hence:

```
X = 1 ;
false.
```

Now we'll look at `max([1,0],X).`:

This is now `acc_max([0],1,X).`. Again, we have two rules, evaluated in the order they appear:

First we see that `0 > 1` is not true, so the first rule fails and we evaluate the second.

Now we see that `0 =< 1` is true, and call `acc_max([],1,X)`. This matches only `acc_max([], A, A).`, and we therefore unify X with 1 (again). We have the solution, and this time we have no unevaluated rules (ie. no unexplored choice points). So now we see:

```
X = 1.
```

... as there is no doubt in Prolog's "mind" that there are no other solutions. If you were to invert the order of the rules:

```
acc_max([], A, A).
acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :- H =< A, acc_max(T, A, Max).
acc_max([H|T], A, Max) :- H  > A, acc_max(T, H, Max).
```

... you would see the behaviour invert as well.

Hopefully this helps to demonstrate that this **is** a consistent and predictable interaction, and should be one shared by all variants of Prolog.

Comment: Excellent answer, especially the last paragraph. An important property of this toplevel behaviour is that it easily lets you detect **unintended** choice points, even if there are no further solutions! This is important because choice points prevent certain optimizations, and of course also do not come for free themselves. In that regard, the current SWI behaviour is a huge improvement over what it previously had.

Comment: You should change your `X = 2`s into `X = 1` in your examples, since your example does not contain 2.

Comment: @Fatalize - thanks! Lazy copy pasta error, whoops. My Xs are no longer 2s.

Comment: You still have one left ;)

Comment: Le sigh - serves me right for hurrying before a meeting